# Meteor and underscoreJS - random array of Integers and its sum incoherent

Tags: javascript, meteor, underscore.js

I'd like to display a randomized array of integers and its corresponding sum.

**Problem:** The results are not coherent.

[image]

My approach:

```
Template.registerHelper('randomNumbers', function () {
    var list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    var resultLength = _.random(1, list.length);
    var result = _.sample(_.shuffle(list), resultLength);
    return {
        result: result,
        total: _.sum(result)
    };
});
```

HTML Template:

```
<template name="displayResults">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            {{randomNumbers.result}}
        </tr>
        <tr>
            total: {{randomNumbers.total}}
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</template>
```

It seems to me that for the calculation of "total" the function of result is called seperately. 
How can i get "result" and "total" synchronized?

Thanks in advance!
Vin

Comment: they will be synchronised. to debug this do 2 things: 1) use console.log to see what the in between steps are doing. 2) don't use random at the start. check that things are working without random and then build on your working example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your template is that you're calling the helper 2 times and due to random it will provide 2 different pairs of (result, total).

By using the `{{#with}}` block helper, you're explicitly calling the helper only once and will display a valid pair.

```
<template name="displayResults">
  <tbody>
    {{#with randomNumbers}}
      <tr>{{result}}</tr>
      <tr>total: {{total}}</tr>
    {{/with}}
  </tbody>
</template>
```